# How to display the read more and read less button in WordPress

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress

I am getting the list from the database and now I have to add the read more and read less button depending upon the content but I am not getting it. I am not getting any error in the console.

```
if($loop->have_posts() ) {
while($loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $tid = $loop->ID;

 $data .='<li>
        
        <div class="overflowSet"><div class="imgwrap" style="background-image:url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($tid).')"></div></div>
        <h5>'.wp_trim_words(get_the_title($tid),9, '...').'</h5>
        <p class="countcontent">'.$the_content.'</p>
    </li>';


    }
}
```

I added the below script to display the read more and less

```
$data .='<script>
jQuery(function($){
var maxLength = 390;
var moretxt = "...Read More";
var lesstxt = "Read Less";

$(".countcontent").each(function($) {
    var myStr = $(this).text();
    if (jQuery.trim(myStr).length > maxLength) {
      var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
      var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
      $(this).empty().html(newStr);
      $(this).append(\'<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>\');
      $(this).append(\'<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more more">' + moretxt + '</a>\');

    }
  });

  $(".read-more").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("more")){
        $(this).removeClass("more");
        $(this).text(lesstxt);
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("more");
        $(this).text(moretxt);
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").hide();
    }

  });

 });

   </script>';
```

I am getting the issue in this code

```
 jQuery(this).append(\'<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>\');
  jQuery(this).append(\'<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more more">' + moretxt + '</a>\');
```

If I add the below code then I am getting the text.

```
 jQuery(this).append(\'<span class="more-text">Read less</span>\');
  jQuery(this).append(\'<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more more">Read more</a>\');
```

Comment: When I checked the inspect element then I am not getting my script and it's only showing the 0

Answer (score 1):

```js
var maxLength = 390;
var moretxt = "...Read More";
var lesstxt = "Read Less";
var removeStr;
var text = $('.countcontent').text();

$(".countcontent").each(function() {
  var textlength = $(this).text().length;
  if (textlength > maxLength) {
    var myStr = $(this).text();
    var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
    var removedStr = myStr.substring(1, maxLength);
    $(this).empty().html(newStr);
    $(this).append('<span class="more more-text">' + moretxt + '</span>');
  } else {
    $(this).append('<sapn class="less less-txt">' + lesstxt + '</a>');
  }
});

$(".more-text").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("more")) {
    $(this).removeClass("more");
    $('.countcontent').empty();
    $('.countcontent').text(text);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("more");
    $(this).text(moretxt);
    $(this).siblings(".more-text").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="countcontent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood your point. and I am not getting the error on this code. I have an issue with my jquery

Comment: I used at the end of the function echo $data; wp_die();

Comment: IF is use there is some issue with append.

Comment: This is why I'm suggested you to console.log removeStr. There is somewhere a failure with the variables removedStr and moretxt. Do a console.log and check the content. If you hardcode it it works as I see from your demo code above.

Comment: I am 100% the issue with append but not able to find the .... is the correct        jQuery(this).append(\'<span class="more-text">'+ removedStr + '</span>\');

Comment: as I see in console.log your removeStr is undefined. Please check.

Comment: It's already defined before the append       var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);

Comment: I comment out the        jQuery(this).append(\'<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>\'); and console.log(removedStr) then i am getting my output

Comment: Please check as answered or upvote if you are satisfied. So I will geht some points. THX

Comment: It will not work with my code because i am using quote and i have to add the code in the function.php

Comment: Also your snippet not working, if i click on read more

Comment: updated my example above. The Read More span is now working. Maybe this is also something for you: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: jQuery(this).append("<span class=\"more-text\">"+ removedStr +"</span>");
jQuery(this).append("<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"read-more more\">Read more</a>");

Comment: Your answer not solved my issue because I am using WordPress.  thank you for the help. Upvote from my side